# Does the Python shell count as a "programming language"?

Tags: discussion

I used the Python shell to answer a question. Is that OK or should I have created a whole program for it?

Comment: As mentioned in the [code golf tag wiki](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info), answers may be [either full programs or functions (or equivalent)](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2419), unless the question overrides this default.